# How do I remove dried gorilla glue from stainless steel sink

Tags: sink, steel, stainless

Sink
[image]
I tried to unstop a bottle of glue and left in sink
Now can't get it up.

Answer (score 1):

Abrasion.

Sandpaper, steel wool, non-woven abrasive pad (better known as the brand name  Scotchbrite® in many places.) Also Bon-Ami cleanser, Lava soap, etc.

Comment: Yup. Mechanical methods (pick, pry, scrape, scrub).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but I just had this issue.  This worked for me and maybe this will help someone.
Cerama Bryte has a kit with a non scratching cleaning pad, razor and cleanser.  I used the razor to carefully remove the big sections and then I used the pad and cleanser.  I had to scrub for a bit but it really helped on my sink.
After that there was a haze for mark where the glue was.  I used a magic eraser to polish it out. 
I know this may not work on everyone's sink, but this is what I did.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good answer: keep 'em coming!